# Sleep a Thread in a loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to make a DieTester for school. One that rolls the dice 100 times and then puts the output in a Table Chart and another table.
The problem is that my Thread wont sleep with the time that is set by the Slider.
Here my DieTester:

```
package sample.Controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.RunnableFuture;

public class DieTester implements Runnable{
private Thread t;
private String Threadname;
List<Integer> List = new ArrayList();
Random rand = new Random();

long l;

public DieTester(String name){
    Threadname = name;
}

public void run() {

    for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(getTime());
            List.add(rand.nextInt(6) + 1);
            System.out.println(List.get(n));

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}

public void start(){
    if (t == null)
    {
        t = new Thread (this, Threadname);
        t.start ();

    }
}

public void setTime(double SliderTime){
    l = (long) SliderTime;
}

public long getTime(){
    return l;
}
}
```

Here the controller:

```
package sample.Controllers;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;


public class Controller {

DieTester dice = new DieTester("Time");

double time=0;
EventHandler e = new EventHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        time = TimeSlider.getValue();
    }
};


@FXML
Slider TimeSlider = new Slider(50, 2000, 50);




@FXML
public void HandlePauseResumeAction(){
}

@FXML
public void HandleStartAction(){
    DieTester die = new DieTester("Start");
    die.start();

}

@FXML
public void HandleSlider(){

    TimeSlider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        time = TimeSlider.getValue() * 20;
        //System.out.println(time);

        dice.setTime(time);

    });

    System.out.println(dice.getTime());



}



}
```

The slider and everything is set up properly. And if I call the getTime() it puts out the time properly, but the Thread isn't sleeping or something.

Comment: As per code,  *Thread.sleep(getTime()); in for loop * will surely do the sleep for current thread for getTime() milliseconds, This call will ensure that the sleep will be for at least the given time, but you can not be sure that the thread will start running exactly after the given time. You can guarantee that the thread will sleep for that much time which is passed in sleep() method, provided there is no interrupted exception otherwise the thread will get InterruptedException which you can verify.

Comment: _"Thread wont sleep with the time that is set by the Slider"_ - does it sleep too much or too little? How much does the actual sleep time differ from the requested time?  Without hard numbers it is very hard to guess what is happening.

Comment: The thread isn't sleeping at all it seems, so your question, it does sleep too little.

Comment: And pbajpai21, what do you mean? You say that I should add the interrupted exception? Because the problem here is, the time long is changing but the thread sleep is not. When I put the long l in the start for 1000, it does sleep a 1000 miliseconds. But when I dont define it in the begin, it just doesn't sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys so I figured it out, this is what I did

```
 @FXML
public void HandleStartAction(){
    start();
}

public void run(){
    for(int n = 0; n < 100; n++){
        try {
            if(!suspend){
                Thread.sleep((long)TimeSlider.getValue() * 20);
                List.add(rand.nextInt(6) + 1);
                System.out.println(List.get(n));
            }else{

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}

public void start(){
    if (t == null)
    {
        t = new Thread (this, "Start");
        t.start ();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a mutable shared variable :

```
long l
```

Threads access it concurrently, (one reads, one writes), yet it doesn't have proper synchronization, so writes of one thread are not guaranteed to be seen by the other thread.

On top of that, l is initialized to 0, and odds are the spawned thread has raced through 100 loops, without really sleeping, before the first property change event happens.

Comment: So what shoud I do?

Comment: Well, use proper synchronization (making l volatile would be enough given your current code).
For the race condition, I don't know, it depends on what you want to achieve. Maybe you want to start with a greater default value, or only start the thread once a non 0 value is known for l?